# How can i delete a windows service by the "Path to executable" not the "Service Name"?

Tags: c#, service

I have a windows service installed.

I have tried to delete by using
sc delete 
or by
InstallUtil.exe /u "C:\Dev\myservice.exe"

But these are command line . I was trying to do it using c#
But is there a command i can use to delete it via the "Path to executable" ?

The reason is i want to write a dll which can be used to do this, as the service name is saved in a config file and the dll wont have any access to the file to get the name , but the path to executable will be the same, or maybe i can delete by just the .exe file ?

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few complications here

1. You can't retrieve the service start executable via a C# API
2. Multiple service instances can be started from a single executable

But fear not! You can get all that you need (with a bit of effort)

Step 1 - get the list of services

```cs
ServiceController[] services = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices("localhost");
```

Step 2 - Get the service executables.

This bit is a bit harder but as [outlined here](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/06/get-windowservice-executable-path-in.html) you can grab the path from the registry directly **(note: you need to run as an admin for this bit)**

```cs
string GetServiceExecutable(string name)
{
    RegistryKey services = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services", false);
    if (services != null)
    {
        return (string)services.OpenSubKey(name).GetValue("ImagePath");
    }
    return null;
}
```

once you have all that matching up the executable with your input & killing the services should be relatively trivial.

Comment: note - I'm on a machine that make elevation to admin difficult, so i haven't tested the second code sample, i'm pretty sure the cast to string is ok there but it might need more work.

Comment: so it would matter if the service is running or not ?

Comment: Pretty sure imagepath is the property for "path to executable" that appears in the service properties dialog within services.msc - which seems to be what you are after.